Could not move temporary workspace - (ionic) android studio
The problem occurred after I updated Android Studio to the latest version, I tried changing the file name again but the problem was not solved, I tried deleting the cache but also, I tried changing the gradle version from 8.7 to 8.6 but the same problem!
I also tried running as administrator, but it didn't work.
I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/79212657/23524201 but it also didn't work
E: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A build operation failed.
    Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5-6d43e532-ec5f-49c1-a66a-8ea5166c7e72) to immutable location (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5)
> Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5-6d43e532-ec5f-49c1-a66a-8ea5166c7e72) to immutable location (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.operations.MultipleBuildOperationFailures: A build operation failed.
    Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5-6d43e532-ec5f-49c1-a66a-8ea5166c7e72) to immutable location (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.markFinished(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.waitForWorkToComplete(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.waitForCompletion(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:107)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.executeInParallel(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.runAll(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactSetResolver$1.run(ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.visitArtifacts(ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.lambda$visitInUnmanagedWorkerThread$0(ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsUnmanagedWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.visitInUnmanagedWorkerThread(ResolvedArtifactSetResolver.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultSelectedArtifactSet.visitArtifacts(DefaultSelectedArtifactSet.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultArtifactCollection.lambda$new$0(DefaultArtifactCollection.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainerFactory$SupplierBackedCalculator.calculateValue(CalculatedValueContainerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer$CalculationState.lambda$attachValue$0(CalculatedValueContainer.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try.ofFailable(Try.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer$CalculationState.attachValue(CalculatedValueContainer.java:224)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer.finalizeIfNotAlready(CalculatedValueContainer.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer.finalizeIfNotAlready(CalculatedValueContainer.java:188)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultArtifactCollection.ensureResolved(DefaultArtifactCollection.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultArtifactCollection.getArtifacts(DefaultArtifactCollection.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.combineToClasspath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:177)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.resolveClassPath(DefaultScriptClassPathResolver.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.lambda$resolveClassPath$0(DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultBuildLogicBuildQueue.build(DefaultBuildLogicBuildQueue.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.resolveClassPath(DefaultBuildLogicBuilder.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.lambda$getInstrumentedScriptClassPath$0(DefaultScriptHandler.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.callAndResetResolutionState(DefaultConfiguration.java:909)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getInstrumentedScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:109)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:120)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultInitScriptProcessor.process(DefaultInitScriptProcessor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler$1.run(InitScriptHandler.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandler.executeScripts(InitScriptHandler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.initialization.InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(InitScriptHandlingSettingsLoader.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.CacheConfigurationsHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CacheConfigurationsHandlingSettingsLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(GradlePropertiesHandlingSettingsLoader.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperationFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareSettings$1(VintageBuildModelController.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$14(StateTransitionController.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:254)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:209)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:80)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getLoadedSettings(VintageBuildModelController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.loadSettings(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.ensureProjectsLoaded(AbstractBuildState.java:115)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleBuildBuilder.create(GradleBuildBuilder.java:58)
    at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.GradleBuildBuilder.create(GradleBuildBuilder.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildScopedBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:207)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:338)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:335)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController$AbstractToolingScope.getModel(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:112)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:116)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getBuildModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getBuildModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:32)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$initAction$5(GradleModelFetchAction.java:181)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.initAction(GradleModelFetchAction.java:180)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.doExecute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:138)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$1(GradleModelFetchAction.java:103)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:73)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.telemetry.GradleOpenTelemetry.callWithSpan(GradleOpenTelemetry.java:61)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$2(GradleModelFetchAction.java:102)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.withOpenTelemetry(GradleModelFetchAction.java:113)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.lambda$execute$3(GradleModelFetchAction.java:101)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.util.GradleExecutorServiceUtil.withSingleThreadExecutor(GradleExecutorServiceUtil.java:18)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:100)
    at com.intellij.gradle.toolingExtension.impl.modelAction.GradleModelFetchAction.execute(GradleModelFetchAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5-6d43e532-ec5f-49c1-a66a-8ea5166c7e72) to immutable location (C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f02f3e6d6b9b05dcbc692afcee81f6e5)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.unableToMoveBecause(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:329)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.lambda$executeMoveOrThrow$1(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:299)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOr(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:290)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOrThrow(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:298)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$moveTemporaryWorkspaceToImmutableLocation$6(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider$1.withTemporaryWorkspace(CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$moveTemporaryWorkspaceToImmutableLocation$7(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep$WorkspaceMoveHandler.executeMoveOr(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:290)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.moveTemporaryWorkspaceToImmutableLocation(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:241)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$executeInTemporaryWorkspace$3(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:220)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.workspace.impl.CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider$1.withTemporaryWorkspace(CacheBasedImmutableWorkspaceProvider.java:119)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.executeInTemporaryWorkspace(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignImmutableWorkspaceStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.executeInCache(IdentityCacheStep.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.lambda$executeDeferred$0(IdentityCacheStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.cache.Cache.lambda$get$0(Cache.java:31)
    at org.gradle.cache.ManualEvictionInMemoryCache.get(ManualEvictionInMemoryCache.java:30)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory$CrossBuildCacheRetainingDataFromPreviousBuild.get(DefaultCrossBuildInMemoryCacheFactory.java:255)
    at org.gradle.cache.Cache.get(Cache.java:31)
    at ....

CONFIGURE FAILED in 10s



Just to clarify, when you say you "tried deleting the cache", do you mean the Gradle cache, i.e. C:\Users\goank\.gradle\caches? And did you just try or did you succeed deleting it (it just didn't solve the issue)?

There have been some bugs in Gradle around this, some have been fixed recently in Gradle 8.11, may be try the latest 8.x build

Man I even deleted C:\Users\goank\.gradle

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

⚠️ Please note that in this method I have reverted to an old version of gradle, so if there are problems or the like, please be careful.
Open File :
<PathProject>\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
Change to :
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-all.zip

and open :
<PathProject>\android\build.gradle
Change to :
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1'

